# 'cannot open shared object file' while running firefox on linux machine

Tags: linux, firefox, xpcom, shared-objects

I recently installed Firefox v45.0.2 on linux machine. After finishing installation I ran `firefox -v` command to check version, however this command is giving me following error:

```
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /opt/firefox-45.0.2/libxul.so:
libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

OS : Ubuntu 15.04

Java : 7

Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

---

> libfontconfig.so.1: No such file or directory

Well, then install the package 'fontconfig'.

But then again, not easy to know the exact package name when your OS is unknown. So please edit your post to include [OS name and version].

---

Comment: Thank you for reply.  I have updated my answer with OS version.

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 - [unknown <arch>]  :  No libfontconfig.so.1 for Ubuntu. Please use an Ubuntu package for firefox, e.g. firefox (47.0+build3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) for Ubuntu 14.04 : Please click either amd64 or i386  http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/firefox .....